# Is it safe to store password in a session context? ADFS

Tags: adfs

I'm playing with adfs, and I'd like to store credentials in a session context during my questioning of the user. So, my question is, is it safe to store sensitive data in a session context?

Thanks

Comment: If you're directly handling credentials (aside from extending the Session Manager) I'd question your approach.  Is your session server side or client side?

Comment: basically I perform questioning. using adfs provider. I ask for a pwd and then I would like to store it, so I can use it later.

Comment: Why do you need to use it later?  That is generally a bad thing.